# How do validation for virtualized listview?

Tags: wpf, validation, listview, virtualization

I have some listView with userControl in ItemTemplate. This UserControl contains some textBoxes that I need to validate. Everything works fine till I enabled Virtualization for ListView. Now validation work only for visible items.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Because the UI virtualization recycles the visual containers, it will reset them, so the solution would be to manually bind to the some properties in the user control, and do your validation in the View Model.  Then when it doesn't pass validation change the border color and size of the UserControl to red and a thicker border.

```
<UserControl...>
  <Grid>
    <Border BorderThickness="{Binding Path=Border_Thickness_property}" BorderBrush="{Binding Path=Border_brush_color}">

    <!-- Put your textboxes and such here... -->

    </Border>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

reference: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization

OR

You could have your View Model implement IDataErrorInfo and use that interface to define your validation rules

[This](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/) site has a nice example.